# WP_Query for posts that have postmeta assigned to a taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, the-events-calendar

Since we're not skinning or using the standard template for this, we've ran into some difficulties but we're at a point we're too far along in the project to turn back. I've never done a WP_Query this fancy but two things to outline how it's structured.

1. I'm querying the post type `tribe_events` where postmeta keys are equal to `_VenueCity`, `_VenueState`, and `_VenueCountry` and values are equal to the GET/POST request.
2. The postmeta is assigned to the `tribe_venue` taxonomy which makes it hard for me to query the postmeta directly since it's not directly attached to the `tribe_events` post type.

I've tried many things but this is what remains of my many different efforts.

```
<?php
    // Support for multiple locations to be filtered.
    $request_cities = array_map(function($item){return utf8_decode(urldecode($item));}, explode('+', $_REQUEST['city']));
    $request_states = array_map(function($item){return utf8_decode(urldecode($item));}, explode('+', $_REQUEST['state']));
    $request_countries = array_map(function($item){return utf8_decode(urldecode($item));}, explode('+', $_REQUEST['country']));

    // If the event only has 1 item convert to string.
    if (is_array($request_cities) && count($request_cities) <= 1) {
        $request_cities = implode("|", $request_cities);
    }
    if (is_array($request_states) && count($request_states) <= 1) {
        $request_states = implode("|", $request_states);
    }
    if (is_array($request_countries) && count($request_countries) <= 1) {
        $request_countries = implode("|", $request_countries);
    }
    $event_args = [];
    $event_args['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key' => '_VenueCity',
            'value' => $request_cities
        ], [
            'key' => '_VenueState',
            'value' => $request_states
        ], [
            'key' => '_VenueCountry',
            'value' => $request_countries
        ],
        'relation' => 'AND'
    ];
    $event_args['tax_query'] = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'tribe_venue',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $request_cities
        ]
    ];
    $events = tribe_get_events($event_args);
?>
```

If someone can help me figure this out I'd be beyond grateful at this point because I've spent so much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: have you tried putting meta query inside tax query? i can't find any documentation for this, just a guess

Comment: also, should field be term_id, or name / slug?

Comment: I just figured it out after tons of searching. Thank you for the help, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution after tons of searching from the events calendar's website and modified it to suit my needs. The code is as shown below: (Note I also removed the array to string conversion since it's pretty pointless.)

```
<?php
    // Support for multiple locations to be filtered.
    $request_cities = array_map(function($item){return utf8_decode(urldecode($item));}, explode('+', $_REQUEST['city']));
    $request_states = array_map(function($item){return utf8_decode(urldecode($item));}, explode('+', $_REQUEST['state']));
    $request_countries = array_map(function($item){return utf8_decode(urldecode($item));}, explode('+', $_REQUEST['country']));

    //Retrieve venues that match query criteria
    $args = [
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post_type' => 'tribe_venue',
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                'key' => '_VenueCity',
                'value' => $request_cities,
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ], [
                    'key' => '_VenueState',
                    'value' => $request_states,
                    'compare' => 'IN',
            ], [
                    'key' => '_VenueCountry',
                    'value' => $request_countries,
                    'compare' => 'IN',
            ],
            'relation' => 'AND'
        ]
    ];
    $venues = get_posts($args);
    $venue_ids = wp_list_pluck($venues, 'ID');
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $event_args[] = [
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                'key' => '_EventVenueID',
                'value' => $venue_ids,
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ]
        ],
        'paged' => $paged
    ];
    $events = tribe_get_events($event_args);
?>
```

Source: https://theeventscalendar.com/support/forums/topic/events-list-with-filter-by-venue-in-custom-template/#post-1290489